# Get an error when building chrome, subprocess.call throws "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, exception, subprocess

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/rule_bison.py", line 75, in <module>
    return Code = subprocess.call([bisonExe, '-d', '-p', prefix, inputFile, '-o', outputCpp])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am trying to use ninja to build chromium source code. Then I got the error above. I don't know how to figure it out. Could you give me any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It means that whatever binary named by the variable `bisonExe` was not found. The `Errno 2` error will be thrown for any non-existent binary:

```
>>> subprocess.call(['spamandeggs', '-V'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice,Martijn Pieters.My Ubuntu didn't install bison. I have installed the bison,now is ok,:)